# HTML sum using JQuery 3

Tags: jquery, html

```html
<div id="base_price">4200</div>
<div id="extra_price">100</div>

<div id="total"></div>
```

i want   automatic sum two value without any action

Comment: Without any calculation: `<div id="total">4300</div>`

Comment: even magic requires a magic word. you need to compute these values on an event

Comment: @freedomn-m This was my laugh of the day. Kunal Sahu This is not possible without an "action". Even the calculation itself is an action.

Comment: You have shown no attempt yourself in doing this at all

Comment: try some thing like this

$(document).ready(function() {
var sum =0;
  $(".totalCal div").each(function(){
  sum = parseInt($(this).text())+sum;
  
  });
$("#total").text(sum);
});

Comment: fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/10772/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below mentioned solution. **But again without any action it would not be possible**.

```js
$('#total').text(parseInt($('#base_price').text()) + parseInt($('#extra_price').text()))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="base_price">4200</div>
<div id="extra_price">100</div>

<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: please share jquery full code

Comment: @KunalSahu: Everything is there on above snippet.